# Missing Sketchflow controls button, checkbox and many others

Tags: silverlight, blend, sketchflow

Missing Sketchflow controls button, checkbox and many others.
Hi when I try to create a sketchflow project and add controls all I get it the default text ones not the Sketchflow hand writing ones :(

All I can find on the web is the advice to uninstall blend then install it again :( this cannot surely be an answer?

Expression Blend 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're dragging from the sketchy style palette.

Answer (score 0):

Are you dragging the controls from the asset panel or the toolbar buttons? By default in Blend 3, the toolbar controls will create the non-sketchy controls, you have to create them from the asset panel under the SketchFlow heading.  In Blend 4, the toolbar controls will create the sketchy controls by default in a SketchFlow project.